# Impossible to add or remove pages dinamically from ViewPager Android Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

I've read all stackOverflow answers regarding this topic, and any of them worked for me, or I couldn't make it myself.

As you can see in the code below, I added the default ViewPager Activity from Android Studio, and now I need to add new pages or remove existing pages from the corresponding buttons.

So, the activity is loading correctly and gets the correct number of pages, and I can also change the information in each of them successfully. As you can see, the app is connected to Firebase and I get from there the total number of pages (dogs) that my activity should have, this is working well.

Now, How can I add a new page, move to that page, and update the adapter and total number of pages?

Same for removing, How can I remove the current page, then move to another one and update the adapter with no problems?

I'm getting totally crazy with this, spent the whole day with diffeent solutions I found in stackoverflow, but could not make it. I'm now confused about when to use the "notifyDataSetChanged()", if it is a good idea override the "getItemPosition" or not, etc.

I would appreciate if someone could finally help me adapting the answer to my project, it's the default ViewPager just modified small parts to try to fix it, but don't know what else I can do.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Note: Some functions like "updateIntValueFromCurrentUser()" are declared in MainActivity but working, they are related to firebase queries etc so I'm not focusing on this.

```
public class DummyViewPagerActivity extends MainActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private static ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy_view_pager);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

//Creating menu bar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dummy_view_pager, menu);
    return true;
}
//Creating the two buttons to save and delete the images
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add:

            updateIntValueFromCurrentUser("dogs_number", person.getDogs_number()+1);
            return true;
        case R.id.edit:

            return true;
        case R.id.delete:

            updateIntValueFromCurrentUser("dogs_number", person.getDogs_number()-1);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy_view_pager, container, false);
            TextView dogName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dog_name);
            dogName.setText(allDogs.get((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) - 1).getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RaisedException()", e.getMessage());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show x total pages.
            return person.getDogs_number();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you should update adapter data and reset to viewPager

Answer (score 1):

Adding/Removing items from FragmentViewPager is a bit tricky thing to do:

Try using this adapter and let me know is it working for you.

```
public class CodebaseFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public CodebaseFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position){
        mFragmentList.remove(position == 0 ? 0 : position - 1);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearAllItems(){
        mFragmentList.clear();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateItem(int position, Fragment fragment){
        mFragmentList.set(position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (mFragmentList.contains(object)) return mFragmentList.indexOf(object);
        else return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how should I adapt this adapter to my project. How do I create the pages with fragments inside in your code? Could you help me to know which modifications should I perform?